# Convert Map<File, File> to Map<File, List<File>> using java 8 stream

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

I have some property files that I save in a Map. Example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", "One");
map.put("2", "Two");
map.put("3", "Two");
map.put("4", "One");
```

I want to convert the `Map<String, String>` to

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

That should be

```
<"One", ("1", "4")>
<"Two", ("2", "3")>
```

And I have some code that I want to rewrite in Java 8 style.

```
  private Map<File, List<File>> getAllFiles(Set<File> files) {
   Map<File, File> inputFilesWithTskFile = 
   AppStorage.getInstance().getApplicationBean().getInputFilesWithTskFile();

    List<File> tsks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<File, File> entry : inputFilesWithTskFile.entrySet()) {
        if (files.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            tsks.add(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    Map<File, List<File>> listTsk = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<File, File> entry : inputFilesWithTskFile.entrySet()) {
        if (tsks.contains(entry.getValue())) {
            List<File> files1 = listTsk.get(entry.getValue());
            if (files1 == null) {
                files1 = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            files1.add(entry.getKey());
            listTsk.put(entry.getValue(), files1);
        }
    }
    return listTsk;
  }
```

Thank you for any help. 
Maybe you know some tutorials that explain how to create Map from Map that on the left side should have value, on the right side should be the list of keys that grouping by value.

Comment: You are probably looking for [Collectors.groupingBy](http://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector).

Comment: Describe your logic - the above snippet is somewhat useless; there are variables that are used but never defined, which makes it impossible to determine what the logic does.

Comment: Yes, definitely grouping, but really don't know how to convert this specific code(

Comment: Describe your usecase please? Your code is not readable and don't post code like so.

Comment: It seems that from your first map, you have some identical values, and want to group by by same values ? and FileList typo of FIle ?

Comment: I added some explanation. I think it could help you

Comment: What is a `FileList`?

Comment: sorry, this my fault, I'll edit now

Comment: Map the `entrySet` of the original map to a new `Map.Entry` with key and value reversed, then group by key.

Comment: @daniu see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49695473/2071828) - you don't need to do that, there are `Collectors` for dealing with that, specifically `Collectors.mapping`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
private Map<File, List<File>> getAllFiles(List<File> files) {
    return AppStorage.getInstance().getApplicationBean().getInputFilesWithTskFile()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> files.contains(e.getKey()))
            .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getValue, mapping(Entry::getKey, toList())));
}
```

i.e. get all the `filesWithTskFile`, filter out the entries in the `Map` where the key is not in the `files`. Then group the `Map` by the `value`.

---

Using

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

---

A more general worked example, with:

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> groupByValue(final Map<String, String> input) {
    return input.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getValue, mapping(Entry::getKey, toList())));
}
```

Running:

```
final Map<String, String> example = Map.of(
        "1", "A",
        "2", "B",
        "3", "A",
        "4", "B"
        );

groupByValue(example).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s->%s%n", k, v));
```

Gives:

```
A->[3, 1]
B->[2, 4]
```

Expanding to:

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> groupByValue(final Map<String, String> input, final Set<String> take) {
    return input.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> take.contains(e.getKey()))
            .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getValue, mapping(Entry::getKey, toList())));
}
```

And running:

```
groupByValue(example, Set.of("1", "3")).forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s->%s%n", k, v));
```

Gives:

```
A->[1, 3]
```

---

**NB:** I used a `Set` rather than a `List` for the filter. A `Set` guarantees that its `contains` method will run in `O(1)`, whereas for a `List` will run in `O(n)`. So the `List` will be **very** inefficient. Depending on the sizes of the inputs, you may actually be better off copying your `List` into a `Set` *before* filtering:

```
private Map<File, List<File>> getAllFiles(List<File> files) {
    final Set<File> filter = Set.copyOf(files);
    return AppStorage.getInstance().getApplicationBean().getInputFilesWithTskFile()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> filter.contains(e.getKey()))
            .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getValue, mapping(Entry::getKey, toList())));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely what I searching for. I am grateful to you, Boris! Thanks!

Comment: @PaulChechegov I was actually surprised how compact it was in Java 8! Do note my warning at the end.

Comment: yeah I saw your last comment, and I'll be use Set instead List in future.